# Get access to array in JSON by ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I use ReactJS to get data from a JSON file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo Fetch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var DataBlock = React.createClass({
            getInitialState:function(){
                return {data:[]};
            },
            componentDidMount:function() {
                var a=this;
                $.getJSON(this.props.url, function(data) {
                    a.setState({data:data})
                });
            },
            render: function() {
                console.log(this.state);
                return (
                        <div>
                            <h1>Sample data block</h1>
                                <h3>{this.state.data.movies[0].title}</h3>
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });
        React.render(
                <DataBlock url="small_data.json"/>,
                document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is JSON file `small_data.json`

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "abridged_cast": [
        {
          "characters": [
            "Dominic Toretto"
          ],
          "id": "162652472",
          "name": "Vin Diesel"
        },
        {
          "characters": [
            "Brian O'Conner"
          ],
          "id": "162654234",
          "name": "Paul Walker"
        }
      ],
      "synopsis": "Continuing the global exploits in the unstoppable franchise built on speed, Vin Diesel, Paul Walker and Dwayne Johnson lead the returning cast of Fast & Furious 7. James Wan directs this chapter of the hugely successful series that also welcomes back favorites Michelle Rodriguez, Jordana Brewster, Tyrese Gibson, Chris \"Ludacris\" Bridges, Elsa Pataky and Lucas Black. They are joined by international action stars new to the franchise including Jason Statham, Djimon Hounsou, Tony Jaa, Ronda Rousey and Kurt Russell.",
      "title": "Furious 7",
      "year": 2015
    }
  ],
  "runtime": 140
}
```

Neither `title` nor anything else is displayed. But when I try to display a non-array object in JSON file, like `runtime`, I just use `{this.state.data.runtime}`, it shows as expected, but how can I get access to `movies` array? I thought I use proper syntax to retrive the array. If it's not like this, what is the true one? How can I get data from objects in array in JSON and store in variables in ReactJS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this, right: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/BoQVoj?editors=001

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Sample data block</h1>
    {this.state.data.movies.map(function(movie, i) {
      return <h3 key={'movie-'+ i}>{movie.title}</h3>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

It loops through the `movies` array and `.map()` returns the value for each movie to be displayed.

Comment: It worth mentioning that it's required to specify `key`

Comment: Thanks @zerkms , I'll add it to the example.

Comment: Sorry, it was missing `return` statement inside map. I'm used to write ES6 arrow syntax, which has return by default... :). Check the example link I provided on the post as well.

Comment: I don't know why it still works on codepen.io but doesn't work when I copy and paste it to my editor and reload

Comment: I updated the example. It uses some endpoint from chriscoyer's codepen example, don't care about that. XHR success callback sets your response JSON to the data state. And it works.

Comment: It still does not, as usual

Comment: @zvona And what I need is to get and store and process data from JSON file, it means do not copy data from them to an object in JavaScript file

Comment: @zvona I managed to use your answer to rectify all things. Thanks, mate

Comment: @zvona if i want to nested array as "abridged_cast": [] , how i will do that?